# Mapserver - Standard Pointsymbolizer edited by SLD

Tags: mapserver, sld

I have pointfeatures in a OpenLayers map. Every feature has a different attribute or several have even more than one attribute. Thus I would like to use not the standard point symbols like that created by Pointsymbolizer. 
Rather I would like to create new points. Is it somehow possible to edit the standard points in the way like filling one point with two colors (one half blue and the other red) by SLD? Or even filling a point with three or four colors?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer right away at mapserver.

Cartographical Symbol Construction with MapServer¶
http://mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/construction.html

Other ideas are very much appreciated!